# wordpress submenu style with has_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

Menu html code:

```
<ul class="align-items-center d-flex">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown mx-2">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#"  role="button" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mx-2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Menu php code in wordpress:

```
<?php
           if (has_nav_menu('header_menu')) {
                wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
                        'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                        'fallback_cb'     => false,
                        'container' => false,
                    )
                );
            }
        ?>
```

How should I code so that the styles are applied?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please create your custom walker class

```
class CustomMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    // Write your logic here
}
```

Provide your customer walker class object to your wp_nav_menu as mentioned below

```
<?php
if (has_nav_menu('header_menu')) {
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
            'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
            'fallback_cb'     => false,
            'container'       => false,
            'walker'          => new CustomMenuWalker()
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Take reference from [here](https://awhitepixel.com/blog/wordpress-menu-walkers-tutorial/) !!